# How to make conditions within a try/except loop?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am webscraping data on two json files.

The first one has some data that I can collect.

The second one does not have the desired data. And I want to store 'NA' instead.

My problem is that I don't know how to store correctly my 'NA' within my script.

Here is my code:

```
import requests

# this is our profile ids
profile=['kaid_896965538702696832878421','kaid_1143236333220233567674383']

# prepare the list to get data
badgechall=[]

# do this for each profile id
for kaid in profile:
    # request the api link of the profile
    data = requests.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/{}/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959'.format(kaid)).json()

    # go through each json file to get the data
    for item in data:
        # try to find on each dictionary of the list the desired data or pass
        try:
            for badges in item['renderData']['badgeCountData']['counts']:
                if badges['typeLabel'] == 'Challenge Patches':
                    badgechall.append(badges['count'])
        except KeyError:
            pass

print(badgechall)
```

When I run this code, I get:
`[100]`

What I would like to get is this:
`[100, 'NA']`

`'100'` corresponding to the first profile `'kaid_896965538702696832878421'` and `'NA'` corresponding to the second profile `'kaid_1143236333220233567674383'`.

I would like to have the data for the first and second links and if there is none return `'NA'`. So we should have a list with only 2 values.

I tried:

```
except KeyError:
    badgechall.append('NA')
    pass
```

But it returns:
`[100, 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']`

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to do, can you please clarify?

Comment: Maybe you want to have `try`/`except` within the `for` loop, instead of a `for` loop within a `try`/`except` block?

Comment: @BenI I tried to clarify. Is it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a function and from that function return the first count, or `"NA"`.

```
def get_badge_count(data, badge='Challenge Patches'):
    for item in data:
        try:
            for badges in item['renderData']['badgeCountData']['counts']:
                if badges['typeLabel'] == badge:
                    return badges['count']
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return "NA"

for kaid in profile:
    data = requests.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/{}/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959'.format(kaid)).json()
    badgechall.append(get_badge_count(data))
```

Afterwards, `badgechall` is `[100, 'NA']`. If you want to match another tag, you could provide it as a parameter, e.g. `get_badge_count(data, 'Sun Patches')`

Comment: How can I make this function work with multiple badge types? For instance if I want to take `'Challenge Patches'`store it in `badgechall`, and `'Sun Badges'` and store it in `badgesun`.

Comment: @RobZ You could add the type of badge as another parameter, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that you want to break out of the for loop?

```
        except KeyError:
            badgechall.append('NA')
            break
```

Comment: I made some clarifications. When I run your script it returns: `[100, 'NA', 'NA']`. But I would like to have the data for the first and second links and if there is none return `'NA'`. So we should have a list with only 2 values.

Comment: You'd probably have to add another `break` for the "positive" case.